# Calling a TaskKey with different settings

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin, sbt-0.13

I'm using the plugin `sbt-assembly` (version 0.13.0), and I would like to call `assemblyPackageDependency` with or without `appendContentHash` depending on some `InputKey`

Basically, I would like to do something like this:

```scala
lazy val isGlobalCached = InputKey[Boolean]("")

lazy val myTask = taskKey[sbt.File]("myTask")

myTask := {
    if (isGlobalCached.value)
        //run with the modified assemblyOption
        //assemblyOption in assemblyPackageDependency ~= { x => x.copy(appendContentHash = true) }
        assemblyPackageDependency.value
    else
        assemblyPackageDependency.value
}
```

but I can't figure out how to set the `assemblyOption` only if the condition is true, and not globally

---

Here are a couple of things I tried that didn't work:

```scala
lazy val isGlobalCached = InputKey[Boolean]("")

lazy val myTask = taskKey[sbt.File]("myTask")

lazy val assemblyPackageDependencyWithHash = taskKey[sbt.File]("assemblyPackageDependencyWithHash")


assemblyPackageDependencyWithHash <<= assemblyPackageDependency
assemblyOption in assemblyPackageDependencyWithHash ~= { x => x.copy(appendContentHash = true) }

myTask := {
    //run with the modified assemblyOption
    if (isGlobalCached.value)
        assemblyPackageDependencyWithHash.value
    else
        assemblyPackageDependency.value
}
```

and:

```
lazy val isGlobalCached = InputKey[Boolean]("")

lazy val myTask = taskKey[sbt.File]("myTask")

lazy val globalCacheConf = config("globalCacheConf")

assemblyOption  in globalCacheConf := (assemblyOption in assemblyPackageDependency).value.copy(appendContentHash = true)

myTask := {
    //run with the modified assemblyOption
    if (isGlobalCached.value)
        assemblyPackageDependency.in(globalCacheConf).value
    else
        assemblyPackageDependency.value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import complete.DefaultParsers._

val myCmd : Command = Command("myCmd")(_ => Space ~> Bool) { (state, globalCached) =>
  val extracted = Project extract state
  import extracted._
  Project.runTask(
    assemblyPackageDependency,
    append(Seq(assemblyOption in assemblyPackageDependency := globalCached), state)
  )
  state
}

commands += myCmd
```

Comment: thanks, command might be the way to do it. I'm using this logic as part of another task. Can I execute the command, to get the result of `assemblyPackageDependency` ?

Comment: The runTask function returns an Option[(State, Result[T])], from which you can get the result of the task.

Comment: Command, unlike task, do not return a value as result. So, if you want to do something with the result of a task, (print the result, for example) you should: 1) do it in the command, after the runTask function call. or 2) define a new task, do it in the new task, and run the new task in the command.